# Enable global middleware only for one environment in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm using a global middleware in Laravel 5 (barryvdh/laravel-cors) but I only want it to be active on one environnement (dev). That's because I only require it with composer in dev environnement, so it's not installed in production.

I registered it has a global middleware in App Kernel and so I have an error if I try to deploy my app in production (`Class 'Barryvdh\Cors\CorsServiceProvider' not found`). I know why, but I'm looking for a solution.

Is there any way to declare a middleware globally in laravel 5 but only required in one environnement ?

I hope it's clear enough, I can edit my post if not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found so far is to check env('APP_ENV') in the Kernel

```
public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
{
    if (env('APP_ENV', 'production') === 'local') {
        $this->prependMiddleware('Clockwork\Support\Laravel\ClockworkMiddleware');
    }

    parent::__construct($app, $router);
}
```

Comment: When I try this in app/Http/Kernel.php I get
    
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Application does not exist' in /home/vagrant/earthport/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 836

Comment: Should be `App::isLocal()`.

Answer (score 9):

To achieve this simply load kernel in the service provider then call either `pushMiddleware` or `prependMiddleware`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        if ($this->app->environment() === 'dev') {
            $kernel->prependMiddleware(ClockworkMiddleware::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel.php file

```
 //...
 protected middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    (!$this->app->environment('local')) ?: 'Path/To/Package'
 ]
```

This should solve.

Comment: Thanks. I can not use "$this" here :/

Comment: how about just $app-> ... or simply app()->

Comment: You can't use anything other than a constant value in an inline property declaration of a class. However you can just as easily implement a constructor that sets this value and then calls the parent constructor

Answer (score 1):

I am new to SO so I am not allowed to comment other answers. I know this is an old topic but thanks to search you still find it.

In the accepted answer a user asked:

> When I try this in app/Http/Kernel.php I get ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Application does not exist' in /home/vagrant/earthport/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 836

I also had this issue and basically you just need to make sure to include the classes

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite query to yours - wanting to implement middleware globally in production but not in local development. I tried the __construct() method EspadaV8 recommended but it did work for me as env('APP_ENV') failed to return a value that I could test.

What I did instead was to include my middleware in the Kernel $middleware array and then, in the `handle($request, Closure $next)` method in my middleware, I bracketed all of my code - except `return $next($request);` - with the following:

```
if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') { 

.......middleware code.......

}
```

Perhaps the opposite would work for you (i.e. === instead of !==)?

I suspect this is not the best solution - as you point out, it would be ideal to handle the loading of the middleware (or not) in the Kernel class but in lieu of finding something better as of yet, I thought to put this solution out there. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I wanted to contribute something that I learned while researching this very same question. I was trying to apply [Spatie's Response Cache](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) package only if debug mode was turned off (so that while I was developing, I wouldn't have to constantly clear the cache to see updates). I wanted to apply the `\Spatie\ResponseCache\Middlewares\CacheResponse` middleware to the `web` middleware group. In order to do this, I followed the advice of @ralphowino, but made the following changes:

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        if (!env('APP_DEBUG')) {
            $kernel->appendMiddlewareToGroup('web', '\Spatie\ResponseCache\Middlewares\CacheResponse');
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.

P.S. I realize that there are many ways to accomplish the objective I explained above such as customizing the Spatie Cache Profile as found in the docs. I just think this is a bit cleaner.