# Laravel application fails when using "config" helper function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to load different middleware for differents environments. Something like:

[Enable global middleware only for one environment in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452814/enable-global-middleware-only-for-one-environment-in-laravel-5)

I was trying to access to the config params using the `config` helper function. Code in `App/Http/Kernel.php`

```
public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
{
    parent::__construct($app, $router);

    $env = 'devel' ;
    $env = config('app.env');

    if ( $env == 'devel' ) {
        $this->prependMiddleware('\App\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfigDevel');
    }        
}
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class config does not exist'
```

If I comment the line:

```
//$env=config('app.env');
```

It works without problem, loading the GlobalConfigDevel middleware. In fact, when using the following route in `routes/wep.php` (which is using the config helper function), it shows the environment param!!

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return dd(config('app.env'));
});
```

Is there any reason for not using helpers functions inside a constructor??

note: a workaround for this problem is using:

```
$env = env('APP_ENV', 'devel');
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `parent::__construct($app, $router);` before the `$env = config('app.env');` line?

Comment: @gbalduzzi good point but the same problem, thanks. edited question.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `config` service is not initialized yet, therefor you cannot access it in the HTTP Kernel constructor.

You can run through your `\App\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfigDevel` for each request and make your test inside it, something like

```
// First lines of \App\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfigDevel@handle
if ( config('app.env') !== 'devel' ) {
    return next($request);
}

// Handle your stuff here otherwise...
```

Comment: Accepted explanation, but I prefer the other solution. I think it is a better approach the use of `env` in the kernel loader constructor, thanks!

Comment: Hi, using the `env` helper in your application is not really a good idea in Laravel, if you use the `config:cache` artisan command, you will not be able to use the `env` helper. The `env` helper should only be used in the config files, see the doc here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching